# Binary Search 2 Lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, binary-search

I was just wondering is there a better way to implement a binary search than I am in my code?  My function is taking 2 two lists - first_booth_voters and second_booth_voters with second_booth_voters being sorted and first_booth_voters not sorted.  I feel like I am making an unnecessary amount of comparisons. Cheers

```
from classes import VoterList
def fraud_detect_bin(first_booth_voters, second_booth_voters):

fraud = VoterList()
comparisons = 0

for i in range(0, len(first_booth_voters)):
    item = first_booth_voters[i]
    first = 0
    last = len(first_booth_voters) - 1

    while first <= last:
        midpoint = (first + last) // 2

        if second_booth_voters[midpoint] == item:
            comparisons += 1
            fraud.append(second_booth_voters[midpoint])
            break 
        else:
            if item < second_booth_voters[midpoint]:
                last = midpoint - 1
                comparisons += 2
            else:
                first = midpoint + 1
                comparisons += 2

return fraud, comparisons
```

Comment: Are you trying to solve the problem, or learning programming / binary search algorithm? If you are more interested in solving the problem, you can use [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html).

Comment: Learning about the algorithm. Cheers.

Comment: Are you sure your algorithm works ? According to what you said - second booth voters being sorted and first booth voters not sorted , you seem to be using opposite , first booth voters as sorted .

Comment: ahh crap I've copied and pasted the wrong version. Cheers

Comment: any chance you could talk me through how to improve it? Thanks

Comment: You can tidy up the for loop to be `for voter in first_booth_voters`, which is simpler and more idiomatic Python. You can also pull `comparisons += 2` up a level - it executes whichever branch you're using.

Comment: Are you sure that `last = len(first_booth_voters) - 1` shouldn't be `last = len(second_booth_voters) - 1` instead? Otherwise you're only searching in the first elements of the second list.

Comment: @Trengot: you should not post broken code on codereview.SE. [It is likely (90%+) that the given implementation is broken unless tests prove otherwise.](http://www.solipsys.co.uk/new/BinarySearchReconsidered.html)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian [Sadly, you are late.](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101344/binary-search-implementation) The question was asked and closed as broken.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian hence the "If this is working code" part.